# Are tid and tgid always the same as pid in the output of ps?

Tags: linux, ps, thread, system-v

In manpage of ps

```
tid         TID          the unique number representing a dispatchable
                         entity (alias lwp, spid).  This value may also
                         appear as: a process ID (pid); a process group
                         ID (pgrp); a session ID for the session leader
                         (sid); a thread group ID for the thread group
                         leader (tgid); and a tty process group ID for
                         the process group leader (tpgid).

   tgid        TGID      a number representing the thread group to which
                         a task belongs (alias pid).  It is the process
                         ID of the thread group leader.
```

In Ubuntu, tid and tgid seem always the same as pid, for both user processes, and kernel threads (I run `ps -o pid,tid,tgid,cmd`) Is it true in Linux, and why?

Is it true in other Unix such as System V or BSD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to task `ps` to show thread information; otherwise it only lists processes:

```
ps -eL -o pid,tid,comm | awk '$1 != $2'
```

will show all the threads, apart from each process’ main thread, *i.e.* entries in the process table where pid and tid are different. The significant option is `-L`: without that, `ps` will only list entries where pid and tid are identical.

On FreeBSD, the equivalent option is `-H`. I haven’t checked other BSDs, or System V.

Comment: Hmm…this actually doesn't give an answer. Are they the same or not.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 `awk '$1 != $2'` should give a strong hint, but I’ve clarified that part.

Comment: Thanks. "On FreeBSD, the equivalent option is -H". BSD style option doesn't have dash, does it?

Comment: @Tim: Linux _ps_ doesn't use a dash, but the actual FreeBSD _ps_ accepts both kinds (because it doesn't have to distinguish: _all_ options in FreeBSD _ps_ are "BSD style" options) and the [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)) actually documents them with a dash.